# Working graph server setup for use with Python3

Tags: database, python-3.x, graph, gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm solving a problem that seems most appropriately handled by a graph database, so I wanted to get a graph database server up and running, and go from there. I'm a Python developer, so I was trying to get something running with the bulbs library, which seems mature and effective, based on the documentation.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any monolithic guide that covers everything between bulbs and an actual graph database server, and my attempts to cobble together working versions have been hampered by a number of compatibility problems.

I feel like I might be missing something intrinsic to the design of these systems. I'm used to postgresql, MariaDB, and other systems which are a pretty simple two-layer model, bridged by a standard API. It seems like the Apache Tinkerpop stack should be what I want, but Rexster seems like it's a server, but not a storage backend, so I still need one of those? I'm a little confused, because Neo4j and Titan seem like they're also servers, in addition to storage backends, so I don't know why Rexster is necessary. Right now, I'm trying to get Neo4j to work with bulbs, but the Gremlin plugin is missing... I've spent more than a day trying to piece this software stack together, and I'm getting really close to just giving up and building a million mapping tables in an ORM.

Is there a monolithic installation guide that I can follow somewhere, or has anyone had experience getting this working in a sane amount of time? I can use any solution deployable on Fedora, Debian, or OpenBSD.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad to provide a good answer. Briefly, I will say that you are not going down a good path. Bulbs is no longer developed. Rexster is TinkerPop 2.x which is a line of code that is no longer maintained. Please see the [TinkerPop web site](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/) which as the full listing of current [python related libraries](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/#language-variants-compilers) for 3.x. However, before you even do that or worry about Titan or Neo4j, you should focus your time on learning the TinkerPop stack itself. Read the [Getting Started](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/tutorials/getting-started/) tutorial. Get comfortable with the [Gremlin Console](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/). Play with [GremlinBin](http://gremlinbin.com/) a bit. Then get into the details of the [reference documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/reference/). If you start more slowly, you will likely have more success.